# Two Feeds combined into one

Tags: javascript, html, feed

So, I have a Materialize CSS based website. 
Materialize CSS is a CSS library, available here, [link](http://materializecss.com).

Now, I managed to display my Blog feed into two columns, going down the first row, then the second row like this.

```
------------------------
Newest     | 4th Newest
2nd Newest | 5th Newest
3rd Newest | 6th Newest
------------------------
```

This is the code used in the one above.

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="firstColumnBlog" class="col s6"></div>
  <div id="secondColumnBlog" class="col s6"></div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.foxinflame.tk/blog/feed/",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find("item").each(function (eachCounter) {
                var title = $(this).find("title").text();
                var description = $(this).find("description").text();
                var comments = +($(this).find("slash:comments").text());
                var pubDate = $(this).find("pubDate").text();
                var link = $(this).find("link").text();
                if(eachCounter < 3){
                  $("#firstColumnBlog").append("<div class='postCollection'><div class='z-depth-1 blogpost' style='min-height: 300px'><br><h5><a style='color:black' href='"+link+"'>"+title+"</a></h5><br><p>"+description+"<br><i>"+comments+" Comments. Published at "+pubDate+"</i></p></div></div>");
                } else if(eachCounter < 6) {
                  $("#secondColumnBlog").append("<div class='postCollection'><div class='z-depth-1 blogpost' style='min-height: 300px'><br><h5><a style='color:black' href='"+link+"'>"+title+"</a></h5><p>"+description+"<br><i>"+comments+" Comments. Published at "+pubDate+"</i></p></div></div>");
                }
            });
        }
    });
  })
</script>
```

Now, I want to add in another feed, to display with the current one. Let's say, a YouTube video feed. It needs to display in the same two columns, in the correct time order, with both feeds mixed.

How would I possibly do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by combining both streams of data, using [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

The calls to `$.ajax` return what are called Promises or [*Deferred*](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) objects. Rather than supply a success function, you chain a `done` method from the `$.ajax` call.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://www.foxinflame.tk/blog/feed/",
  dataType: "xml"
}).done(function(xml) {
  // do stuff with xml
});
```

It's possible to combine two functions that

```
var blogFeed  = $.ajax({ /* some settings */ });
var videoFeed = $.ajax({ /* some other settings */ });

$.when(blogFeed, videoFeed)
  .done(function(blogXML, videoXML) {
    // this will be called when both AJAX requests are successful
  });
```

When you get to this point, you can simply combine both feeds and sort them with a custom sorting function.

```
var combined = blogXML.find('item').concat(videoXML.find('item'));

var sorted = combined.sort(function(a, b) {
  // not all date formats can be compared like this
  // but I don't know what format your dates are in
  var dateA = Date.parse(a.find('pubDate'));
  var dateB = Date.parse(b.find('pubDate'));
  return dateB - dateA;
});

sorted.forEach(function(item, index) {
  // do something with each item
  // (this will probably involve inserting them into the DOM)
});
```

Comment: It looks like this would work. But, so, if the Video XML uses <entry> tags, I change the first line on the third Code Piece to find the Entry tag instead of Item, right?

Comment: Exactly, whatever you need to do to get a list of items back.

Comment: Oh no. But for YouTube, it goes <entry>, to get the Author and URL of the Video, then into <entry><media:group> to get the Video name and description. Would it just be `find('media:group')` ?

Comment: Possibly, you want to get the very first tag you find outside the tags you care about getting data from.

Comment: Eh. My dates, are different. My Blog Feed displays it like this: `Wed, 21 Oct 2015 16:09:00 +0000`, while my Video Feed displays it like this: `2015-11-05T21:00:03+00:00`. Would I use a RegEx, then how? This, I say might be a different topic. But just a hint, or a complete answer. Just for my sake. Please.

Comment: You should be able to parse any standardised date format using [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94458/discussion-between-pokekart2002-and-dan-prince).